# How to solve these logcat errors?

Tags: java, android, timer, runtime-error

In my quiz game i set number of rounds to 15. Whether answer is wrong or right game not terminate. On right answer its increment score otherwise decrement. My quiz game works properly but i added timer in that so that when times up next question come and score decremented. And after adding timer and decrement method in finish() method of timer. My game works for only 8 or 9 rounds and terminates. And also score decremented by 150. But in my decrementScore() method i set decrement by 50 only. Without adding this method in timer's finish method its work proper. My code and log cat is below:- 
Thanks in Advance!

Code :-

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.question);
            processScreen();
    }

   private void processScreen()
   {
                /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer5);
        nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);

        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView timers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                timers.setText("Time: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() { 
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                     processScreen();
                                   }
         }.start();
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.answer5)
        {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
         int id) {
                finish();
                 }
             }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

                }

        else
        {
            if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(i);
        }
        }
      }



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

        Button b=(Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();

            //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
            {
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answercolor);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                currentGame.incrementScore();
            }
            else{
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.answercolorr);
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                currentGame.decrementScore();
            }
            return true;
        }

}
```

Class where score decrement and round increment log cat showing some error in getNextQuestion() method.

```
public class GamePlay {

    private int numRounds;
    private int difficulty;
    private String playerName;
    private int score;
    private int round;

    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    /**
     * @return the right
     */
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    /**
     * @param right the right to set
     */
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    /**
     * @return the round
     */
    public int getRound() {
        return round;
    }
    /**
     * @param round the round to set
     */
    public void setRound(int round) {
        this.round = round;
    }
    /**
     * @param difficulty the difficulty to set
     */
    public void setDifficulty(int difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }
    /**
     * @return the difficulty
     */
    public int getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }
    /**
     * @param questions the questions to set
     */
    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    /**
     * @param q the question to add
     */
    public void addQuestions(Question q) {
        this.questions.add(q);
    }

    /**
     * @return the questions
     */
    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }


    public Question getNextQuestion(){

        //get the question
        Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());
        //update the round number to the next round
        this.setRound(this.getRound()+1);
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * method to increment the number of correct answers this game
     */


    /**
     * method to increment the number of incorrect answers this game
     */
    public void incrementScore(){
        score=score+100;
    }

    public void decrementScore()
    {
        score=score-50;
    }
    /**
     * @param numRounds the numRounds to set
     */
    public void setNumRounds(int numRounds) {
        this.numRounds = numRounds;
    }
    /**
     * @return the numRounds
     */
    public int getNumRounds() {
        return numRounds;
    }

    /**
     * method that checks if the game is over
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isGameOver(){
        return (getRound() >= getNumRounds());
    }


}
```

log cat:-

```
09-06 15:29:23.321: D/dalvikvm(3372): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-06 15:30:00.081: D/gralloc_goldfish(3942): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-06 15:30:05.321: D/dalvikvm(3942): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 7% free 2661K/2844K, paused 86ms, total 97ms
09-06 15:30:05.371: I/dalvikvm-heap(3942): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.795MB for 2160016-byte allocation
09-06 15:30:05.421: D/dalvikvm(3942): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 4768K/4956K, paused 56ms, total 56ms
09-06 15:30:05.541: D/dalvikvm(3942): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 4767K/4956K, paused 8ms+35ms, total 118ms
09-06 15:30:09.050: D/dalvikvm(3942): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16K, 3% free 5226K/5388K, paused 60ms, total 72ms
09-06 15:30:09.080: I/dalvikvm-heap(3942): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.300MB for 2160016-byte allocation
09-06 15:30:09.190: D/dalvikvm(3942): GC_CONCURRENT freed 242K, 6% free 7093K/7500K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 105ms
09-06 15:30:10.140: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 768 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:12.360: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:13.364: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:16.191: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:17.191: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:20.225: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:21.251: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:22.951: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:23.934: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:26.042: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:27.050: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:28.821: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:31.370: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:31.830: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:32.447: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:33.474: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:34.501: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:35.981: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:36.991: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:38.008: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:40.082: I/Choreographer(3942): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-06 15:30:40.181: D/AndroidRuntime(3942): Shutting down VM
09-06 15:30:40.181: W/dalvikvm(3942): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 15
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.abc.cyk.quiz.GamePlay.getNextQuestion(GamePlay.java:100)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.abc.cyk.QuestionActivity.processScreen(QuestionActivity.java:42)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.abc.cyk.QuestionActivity.access$0(QuestionActivity.java:36)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.abc.cyk.QuestionActivity$1.onFinish(QuestionActivity.java:98)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 15:30:44.592: E/Trace(3971): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-06 15:30:44.691: D/dalvikvm(3971): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 7% free 2413K/2592K, paused 27ms, total 29ms
09-06 15:30:44.711: I/dalvikvm-heap(3971): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.553MB for 2160016-byte allocation
09-06 15:30:44.821: D/dalvikvm(3971): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 4521K/4704K, paused 107ms, total 107ms
09-06 15:30:44.871: D/dalvikvm(3971): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 4521K/4704K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 50ms
09-06 15:30:45.341: D/gralloc_goldfish(3971): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-06 15:30:47.540: I/Choreographer(3971): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I discovered where errors im my code. finish() method in countdown timer method stops completing loop and decrement method decreases score on every round instead of decreasing it on times up. Can someone know how to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 15, size is 15
09-06 15:30:40.191: E/AndroidRuntime(3942):     at com.abc.cyk.quiz.GamePlay.getNextQuestion(GamePlay.java:100)` You have tried to get the 16th question when the question array only has 15 questions.

Comment: Your throwing an IndexOutOfBounds exception with one of your arraylists, I couldn't follow your code fully due to being on a phone ad the format of it but I think it's where you get the next question.. You plus 1 to the round which if you do that at the beginning and through out you will go above its index due to starting at 1 and not 0... Sorry if my comments confusing

Comment: sorry its 15 rounds. By mistake i wrote 20 in my explanation first. Its work proper only 7 or 8 rounds.

Comment: @Ryan Hurling yes its confusing.

Comment: @Simon any solution of these errors?

Comment: @Ryan so whats the way to solve it?

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger.  Step through your code so that you understand how it works and watch the variables.  It doesn't matter how many rounds you say you have, the error is very clear.  You tried to get the 16th element from an array that only has 15 elements.

Comment: @Ryan i am not clear when you using computer plz help me...

Comment: It sadly won't be till the evening as I'm at work... Keep trying, if you are still having troubles then, then I shall see what I can do :)

Comment: Bro. like first without timer my game work upto 15 rounds as i want. but when i added timer and when time up next question came. maybe i have to make some changes in rounds method so that when question skip it increases count by 1. but i dont know what changes i have to made. May be this is the problem. what you think?

Comment: You should listen to wise advice.  If you knew how to use the debugger, you would solve this problem in 15 minutes.

Comment: @Simon i dont know how to use debugger efficiently. Can you have any link where i learn how to use it?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Comment: I agree with Simon, if you know how to use the debugger effectively... It will help you here and in future projects..

Comment: @Simon you teach me one new thing. I am very thankful to you. I discover two things while i debugging my quiz game. During debugging its work for 15 rounds and about decrementScore() method in that i added in finish() method of countdown timer. Its work in every round and decrement score. But i want only decrement score only on time's up. Pz help me to solve score problem. And tell me why in emulator my game not works upto 15 round in debugging it is.

Comment: @Ryan you can also see what is the problem now. Having any solution?

Comment: @RyanHurling i updated the code and where i have problem. plz check it out.

Comment: @Simon i updated the code and where i have problem. plz check it out.

Comment: are you still having the same problem?

Answer (score -1):

Errors shown in that view are compilation errors. That's not what he wants. He wants runtime errors. He is doing it correctly, however he doesn't seem to be pasting his entire logcat output, as none of the lines he has posted are error lines.

EDIT: Or rather, they are system-level errors that can be ignored by the developer as they are handled by the system automatically. What you need to be watching for are uncaught exceptions, such as NullPointerException, or IllegalStateException, etc... These are application-level errors and ones that you need to fix.

Comment: Errors with com.abc.cyk are runtime errors i think. Because its in red color in log cat.

Comment: Give me some sensible answer.